# Using android-unused-resources

Tags: java, android, jar, terminal

I am trying to use [android-unused-resources](http://code.google.com/p/android-unused-resources/) to remove unwanted resources in my project.I downloaded the jar file.Its written "ensure your working directory is the root of your Android project".My project structure is like this-
Project(parent folder)-[app,build,facebook,,gradle,volley](inside parent folder)
I tried placing jar file along with parent folder, inside parent folder and inside app folder  and running following command from terminal from respective directory-

```
java -jar AndroidUnusedResources1.6.2.jar
```

but all of them give error-

```
The current directory is not a valid Android project root.
```

Comment: Are you using android-studio?

Comment: @Apurva yeah i am using android studio

Comment: Where have you copied `.jar` file?

Comment: @Apurva I tried placing jar file along with parent folder, inside parent folder and inside app folder which contains source but none of them worked..where should i place jar file?I am confused..

Comment: @Apurva Have u ever used this library?

Comment: of course, in my current project I'm using osmdroid library, and I suggested the method I used.

Comment: @user3684678 Why are you using this? Android's gradle plugin does this on release with Proguard. Also, you can simply run `gradlew lint` on your project or `Analyze -> Inspect Code` and it will tell what resources are unused.